# Integrating function with two variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Hey I'm having trouble integrating a function in MATLAB, constantly getting errors. I'm trying to fill a matrix with the function. exp(x-1)*x^j+k

```
I2 = zeros(26,3);
k = [0.13, 0.0024, 0.000035];
for i = 1:length(k)
    for j = 0:25
        fun = @(x,j) exp(x-1).*x.^j+k(i); 
        I2(j,i) = integral(fun,0,1);
    end %end j-loop
end %end i-loop
display(I2);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the "trouble" ? Why are you not using `integral2` for an integral with two variables ?

Comment: keep getting errors. I'm not using integral2 because I'm only doing an integral in respect to x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current form the function handle is expecting two inputs but you want a function with a single input for `integral`. Changing your function handle definition to the following should fix this.

```
fun = @(x) exp(x-1)*x^j+k(i);
```

Comment: Got the error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

Not quite sure what's wrong with the code :/

Comment: MATLAB uses 1 based indexing, `j = 0:25` will not work, use `j = 1:26` and subtract 1 from j in the function.